# Does (be to bear) _sound natural to you or it does old-English?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

[image]

Hi, I found this image, I don't know if it is correct or a common structure to say;
I am to buy a guitar
he is to pay me back
she is to marry me
does this structure show a kind of future tense?
by the way, I don't know if this is the right site to ask this kind of question or I should go to another community like English language learners.

Comment: 1) It's on topic here since one tends to be very proficient in English (not simply a first time learner of English) before worrying about archaic English. 2) 'is to X' sounds like archaic modern English. Middle English (before 1500?) is very hard to understand for modern English speakers and Old English is impenetrable. So one would call this phrasing of 'is to bear' archaic or old fashioned (or even KJV for King James Version).

Comment: @Mitch: I don't think "is to X" is archaic - for example, it's in this [news headline](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-bristol-57500448) from yesterday.

Comment: @psmears good point. A little formal then? Yes, archaic is a bit strong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"be" + *to* + the infinitive can be used to express future events in contemporary English, mainly something that is arranged for the near future or something you are obliged to do. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going-to_future#The_be_+_to_construction) calls it the "*be* + *to* construction".

In this case "be" is used as an auxiliary verb: see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be), specifically under "auxiliary verb": 4. "used with the infinitive with to to express futurity, arrangement in advance, or obligation". Merriam-Webster gives as an example: "I am to interview him today". It can also be used to express "future in the past" with a past-tense form of "be", e.g. "She was to become famous."

As mentioned, it commonly suggests a future event that is already arranged or something out of duty, rather than something vaguer or more distant. Wikipedia says it is normally used of the near future.

It perhaps isn't used as commonly as [other versions of the future](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future) (English has many ways of expressing future including "I will go...", "I'll go", "I'm going to go...", present tense, or present continuous) but it's still valid ("I am to go..."/"I'm to go..."). It is sometimes suggested to be old-fashioned, but to me "I'm to bring him coffee" or "I'm to see her later" sounds normal, although slightly more formal than some ways of expressing obligation (e.g. "I got to" or "I've got to" are less formal/standard).

"Your wife Sarah is to bear you a son" has that sense of something already arranged (although Biblical English is often not very similar to everyday English, depending on the Bible translation). It sounds quite formal and portentious, although in spoken English you'd say "Sarah's" not "Sarah is" which adds to the formality.

As well as the Bible, this form of words also seems common in news headlines, as psmears mentions in a comment. Perhaps this is because of its brevity and because it emphasises that something is arranged to happen soon. It's possible to drop the copula in a headline, so "President to visit" rather than "President is to visit".